# Wireless Card installation; wire connection broke

Tags: wireless-networking

I bought an Intel NUC, and the golden connector at the end of the black wire disconnected from the wire; this is the wire that is used to attach to the wifi card... How can I fix that?

[image: Photo]

Comment: *"the golden connector"* -- That's probably brass.  Can you post pictures?  What's on the other end of that cable?  If both ends are connectorized, then it should be easy to replace the entire cable assembly.  If it's soldered, then do you know how to solder?  Antenna connectors are usually the reverse SMA or SMC type.

Comment: @sawdust http://www.laptopparts101.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/mini-pci-e-wireless-card.jpg

That isn't my exact setup, but the connector that connects the wire to the card is disconnected.

Comment: The connector that was attached to the wire should be removable (unscrew-able?) from the board, which seems to be an Intel 4965AGN.  There are replacement cable+antenna; see the "Frequently Bought Together" internal antenna on the [Amazon page](http://www.amazon.com/Intel-4965AGN-Next-Gen-Wireless-N-Network/dp/B000RFPBQQ/ref=pd_sxp_grid_pt_0_1).